# Save email into firebase database using hashmap

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

OK so I want to store the email of the users into my database whenever he/she click on one of the name in the listview. Email of course will be stored according to the name the user clicked. However I'm getting this error and I have little knowledge about using hashmap. So can someone help me fix this?

MainActivity:

```
listViewTeams.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //getting the selected team
            Team team = teams.get(i);
            //checkMember(team.getTeamName());
 FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

final String teamMember = user.getEmail();
            final String name = team.getTeamName();
            final String encodedEmailAddress = encodeUserEmail(teamMember);
            databaseMembers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(!dataSnapshot.child("members").child(name).child("teamMember").hasChild(encodedEmailAddress)){
                        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.put("member",encodedEmailAddress);
                        databaseMembers.child(name).child("teamMember").updateChildren(map);
                        //databaseMembers.child(name).child("teamMember").setValue(encodedEmailAddress);

                    }
                    else{

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            //creating an intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatRoomActivity.class);

            //putting team name and id to intent
            intent.putExtra(TEAM_ID, team.getTeamId());
            intent.putExtra(TEAM_NAME, team.getTeamName());

            //starting the activity with intent
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

static String encodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(".", ",");
}
static String decodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(",", ".");
}
```

Member.java

```
public class Member {
private String teamMember;


public Member(){

}

public Member(String teamMember){
    this.teamMember = teamMember;
}

public String getTeamMember() {return teamMember;}
public void setTeamMember(String teamMember) {this.teamMember = teamMember;}
}
```

Team.java:

```
public class Team {
private String teamId;
private String teamName;
private String teamSport;
private String teamOwner;
private String date;
private String time;

public Team() {

}

public Team(String teamId, String teamName, String teamSport, String teamOwner, String date, String time) {
    this.teamId = teamId;
    this.teamName = teamName;
    this.teamSport = teamSport;
    this.teamOwner = teamOwner;
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
}

public String getTeamId() {return teamId;}

public  String getTeamName() {
    return teamName;
}

public String getTeamSport() {
    return teamSport;
}

public String getTeamOwner() { return  teamOwner; }

public String getDate(){ return date; }

public String getTime() { return time; }

}
```

Database:

[image]

Logcat:

```
04-15 14:41:47.914 2483-2483/com.example.user.stfv2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.example.user.stfv2, PID: 2483
                                                                  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Maps with non-string keys are not supported
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzaz(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzaG(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.updateChildren(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.example.user.stfv2.MainActivity$8.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:372)
                                                                      at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Let me know if there is any lack of information. Thank you.

Edited:
Ok, so now I have changed my code a little bit, I removed the checkMember() function and straight put the code in the onClick. So now I can successfully insert the current user's email into the database as one of the team member as shown in my updated database. The problem is now my code will replace the member instead of adding if the email does not exist in the database. So I'm still stuck with unable to add member, is it because the name "member" cannot repeat in the database? Do note that the error has disappear so ignore it.

Comment: From a quick scan it looks like `team.getTeamName()` returns something that is not a `String`. That would then lead to the error message.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, but then the code wouldn't have compiled, right? He tries to `put()` on a `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: Good point. Any idea where else the non-String might be coming from?

Comment: @Frank Just want to ask do you know how to make your post appear in the front page like bump it up or something? I don't want my post to get buried and I have to make another question again.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/getting-attention-for-unanswered-questions

Comment: I have edited my question, I'm closer to achieve what I want now, the problem is the new email will replace old email.